# Opencart: admin category list display by user_id

Tags: php, mysql, database, opencart

i have 3 users my opencart admin, as follows:

- user_id=1
- user_id=2
- user_id=3

what my question is, if `user_id=1` User add some categories to admin category list (eg: computer, cellphone, tab, etc.) when `user_id=2` or other users login time no need to display... i mean what each users added to categories lists, that only show when they logged their user account... dont allow to show other users...

sql

```
public function getCategories($parent_id = 0) {
    $category_data = $this->cache->get('category.' . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . '.' . (int)$parent_id);

    if (!$category_data) {
        $category_data = array();

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "category c LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "category_description cd ON (c.category_id = cd.category_id) WHERE c.parent_id = '" . (int)$parent_id . "' AND cd.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "' ORDER BY c.sort_order, cd.name ASC");

        foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
            $category_data[] = array(
                'category_id' => $result['category_id'],
                'name'        => $this->getPath($result['category_id'], $this->config->get('config_language_id')),
                'status'      => $result['status'],
                'sort_order'  => $result['sort_order']
            );

            $category_data = array_merge($category_data, $this->getCategories($result['category_id']));
        }   

        $this->cache->set('category.' . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . '.' . (int)$parent_id, $category_data);
    }

    return $category_data;
}
```

any idea.?? thanks...

Comment: You need to add a field to the category table in the database to store user this category belongs to. Then you could check and filter categories by this value either in the controller or in your query in the model. You will also need to filter product to hide those in other user's categories.

Comment: If You need this only fot categories I'd stick with what B-and-P suggests. But if You need this for everything (products, manufacturers, informations, modules, etc) then I'd go another way and create a special `audit` table where You would store information like `user_id`, identifier (e.g. `category` or `product`) and their `id`. Then You would have edit almost all queries that save, update, delete and read the information within a database.